# 51 Degrees Mobi keeps doing unwanted redirects. How to stop?

Tags: redirect, 51degrees

I just recently installed the 51 Degrees Mobi Nuget packages to Visual Studio 2015. I have come across an annoying feature that I am not able to figure out how to turn off. When I browse to my site with a mobile device, it automatically redirects the device to /Mobile/Default.aspx.

I don't want this. I want the device to go to the requested URL. Per the documentation found [Here](https://51degrees.com/Developers/Documentation/APIs/NET-V32/Web-Apps/Configuration/Redirect), it says

> This element determines how mobile devices should be redirected. If it is omitted, redirection will be disabled.

This is simply not working as described. I have removed that element in the 51Degrees.config file along with its SectionGroup, yet this unwanted redirection continues. How do I actually disable this annoying feature?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, a little less frustrated now and can think a bit clearly. I read in another post about a cookie being set with a redirect value. After I cleared the cookies on the clients, this problem went away.